# И/ИЛИ-деревья. Алгоритм обхода

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Возникла проблема.
Нужно обойти И/ИЛИ-дерево, при этом нужно запомнить все возможные варианты.
Одна линия - это И-вершина, две линии - это ИЛИ-вершина.
Не могу придумать как запомнить все возможные варианты.
Прикладываю изображения, что я имею ввиду под вариантами и само дерево. В какую структуру лучше их записывать и как лучше это организовать?
Заранее спасибо...

Само дерево,

[image: Само дерево]

результат одной из вариаций
[image: 1 вариант обхода]

следующий вариант
[image: следующий вариант]

последний результат который мы должны получить. 
[image: последний результат]

Comment: а какие операции делать надо?

Comment: @pavel нужно просто составить все возможные варианты дерева. Вообще конечные узлы это объекты. У них будет поле цена и надо подсчитать общую сумму каждого варианта. После отсеять те что не входят в веденную цену и выбрать самый оптимальный вариант. Но проблема у меня в том как обойти исходное дерево и запомнить все эти возможные варианты.

Comment: @Grundy большое спасибо!)

Comment: Вы бы ещё объяснили, как выглядят входные данные. И как должны выглядеть выходные тоже можно добавить, кстати.

Comment: @AivanF. Пишу всю задачу целиком. Задачу задали в универститете. Необходимо с помощью И/ИЛИ-дерева реализовать сбор автомобиля.   Вершины Г,D,M это будет типа двигатель, корпус, шины. В чем заключается моя задача задача. Придумать логику для вершин и запомнить все варианты которые возможны их я уже привел. Насчет выходных данных: должно получится что-то вроде того что на изображении. Как я себе все представляю. Будет дерево. У узлов есть метка(И или ИЛИ) и может быть несколько потомков.

Comment: В момент прохождения по дереву мы и создаем наши все возможные варианты. например когда мы прошли вершину (Г) мы должны уже иметь 4 варианта. после того как мы прошли вершину (Z) количество вариаций увеличилось в двое, после вершины (С) количество вариаций опять же увеличивается в 2 раза. После того как мы прошли (M) наше количество вариаций увеличилось в 3 раза . Как мне запомнить все вершины и все их вариации....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял что именно нужно.

Есть дерево, в вершине есть флаг и/или, нужно посчитать количество способов выбрать все листья из дерева.

Решение - простейшая динамика по дереву. В вершине будем хранить число способов построить поддерево.

Инициализая - в листьях 1.

Пересчет- рекурсия, а ходе которой вычисляются значения для всех потомков. Результат в вершине сумма (для или) или произведение (для и) всех значений в потомках.

Ответ на задачу - значение в корне.

Если вам нужны сами варианты то хранить не количество а список списков и аккуратно реализовать операции (сложение -просто соединить списки, умножение - все варианты выбрать по 1 списку из каждого поддерева)

Comment: Да. Ты правильно меня понял. Можешь пожалуйста если у тебя есть мысль как это сделать расписать алгоритм как будет происходить запись в список, если у меня будут только ветви Г и M.

Comment: @WilpKron ну в лист дерева пишем его имя, тут всё просто, потом для вершины ИЛИ просто копируем по очереди всё из потомков, тоже вроде не сложно. Для И всё чуть хитрее, я бы сделал так: скопировал всё из 1 потомка в вершину,`Tmp =Cur.getlist(); Cur.getlist().clear();  for (list : Tmp) for (list2 : Ptm) Cur.getlist().add(list + list2);` Это пример на псевдокоде. Выполнять для каждого потомка по очереди.